# how i get access property of the outer data-item of a listview in the layout template of inner nested listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvOuter" DataKeyNames="Id">
    <LayoutTemplate>

    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvinner" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSource='<%# Eval("Collection") %>'
            OnItemDataBound="lvGoalsInner_DataBound">
            <LayoutTemplate>
             **Set X from the outer listview**
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Where X is a property of the class whose objects are assigned to the parent data source.

Comment: What is your question / issue here do not post your issue as a Title.. many will probably not respond in regards to offering feasible help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvinner" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSource='<%# Eval("Collection") %>'
      OnDataBound="lvGoalsInner_DataBound">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:Literal 
       runat="server" 
       ID="ltTitle" 
       Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval((Container.Parent as ListViewDataItem).DataItem, "Title") %>' />
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

```
protected void lvGoalsInner_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as ListView).FindControl("ltTitle").DataBind();
        }
```

The handler is for DataBound not, ItemDataBound.